# Why my output image is not seamless?

Tags: 2d, shaders, textures, directx, hlsl

I offset a region of an image but when I tried to restore it using same method it doesn't look right. here is my input and output:

[image]

And this is the code I used to restore :

```
sampler2D InputTexture ;

float4 main(float2 uv : TEXCOORD) : COLOR
{

if(uv.x >0 && uv.x <=0.25 )
    {
    float2 pos = frac(float2((uv.x ),(uv.y + 0.25)));
    return tex2D(InputTexture, (pos));    
    
    }
    
    else{
    return tex2D(InputTexture, uv);    
    }
```

what is wrong?

Comment: Is mipmapping enabled for this texture?

Comment: @DMGregory I know there is mipfilter but I don't know where to add it in fx file